# Pull to Refresh plug-in : PullToBounce Wrapper UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, wrapper, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to use this plugin as refresh action : https://github.com/entotsu/PullToBounce

One, issue is I can't understand his explanation.

[Explanation given on the github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5gSX.png)

tableView.frame = yourFrame --> tableView is equal to scrollView.frame in my situation

yourFrame --> I have no idea what it is. The main frame ? Another Frame I have to create ?

bodyView.addSubview(tableViewWrapper) --> bodyView ? Main Frame here ? or Another frame ?

Here is my code for the scrollView for now. Any help on how to implement this plugin using a scrollView made via the storyboard.

```
    class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

func makeMock() {
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 64)
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightBlue
    self.view.addSubview(headerView)

    let headerLine = UIView()
    headerLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 8)
    headerLine.layer.cornerRadius = headerLine.frame.height/2
    headerLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8)
    headerLine.center = CGPoint(x: headerView.frame.center.x, y: 20 + 44/2)
    headerView.addSubview(headerLine)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue


    let bodyView = UIView()
    bodyView.frame = scrollView.frame
    bodyView.frame.y += 20 + 44
    self.view.addSubview(bodyView)

    let tableViewWrapper = PullToBounceWrapper(scrollView: scrollView)
    bodyView.addSubview(tableViewWrapper)

    tableViewWrapper.didPullToRefresh = {
        NSTimer.schedule(delay: 2) { timer in
            tableViewWrapper.stopLoadingAnimation()
        }
    }

   makeMock()
}

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
}
```

}

One thing, I notice is that there is a View on top of my scrollView that disable me to view it and scroll it. Help here needed please.

Regards,

Hary

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Example](https://github.com/entotsu/PullToBounce/tree/master/PullToBounce/Example) of this library.

yourFrame is nothing but your tableview class. For example if your tableView Class is named `SampleTableView`, then it goes like

`let tableView = SampleTableView(frame: self.view.frame, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)`.

You have to use another class to set up your tableView.

Comment: I did take a look on the example. He implemented his tableView via swift files. I already implemented my scrollView via storyboard. It's ready to go actually. SampleTableView is a class, he created to build his table view. I already have scrollView. Checkout my code, I think I did as he said. Thank you for the reply !

Comment: You are saying that tableView is my scrollView so what is yourFrame here then... I don't see the point of the line. "scrollView.frame = yourFrame" ?

Comment: You have to conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate` by implementing
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
    }

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView!, velocity:     CGPoint, inout targetContentOffset: CGPoint) {
      }

Just making a reference outlet doesn't make your class a UIScrollView.

Comment: So your solution is not use the pod at all ? I kinda want to use it. I am pretty close to it !!!

Comment: I never said that. :/

Comment: My bad... i now understand what you're are saying. But why not? It's obviously a scrollView.

Comment: No. It isn't. It's just another viewController inherited from UIViewController only **having** a scroll view. That doesn't make it a scroll view class.

Comment: Hmm.. I mean there are some elements in there, with a tableView with a prototype cell.

Comment: What you do on the storyboard doesn't affect your class. The vice - versa is true.

Comment: But I still don't get it. Do we have to do this to fix this problem ? Because, I am pretty sure, I am not using it in the right way.

Comment: Can you give me an example ? Because, now i made some changes in my storyboard. It contains a TableView only. But i think the problem comes when i try to wrap a table already existing in the storyboard and add that new view into the Main View on top of the already existing table.